# I'm trying to delete a row in a SQLite3 table by it's row index via input statement in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

While I run this code:

```
delCard = input('Which card do you want to delete?: ')
c.execute ("DELETE from cards WHERE ROWID = int(delCard)");
conn.commit()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\cc7.py", line 74, in <module>
    deleteAcard()
  File "H:\cc7.py", line 42, in deleteAcard
    c.execute ("DELETE FROM cards WHERE ROWID = idrow");
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: idrow
```

Comment: What I don't understand is that how I did it, with your help '''(c.execute ("DELETE from cards WHERE ROWID = ?", delCard);''' works BUT: The ROWID is an integer by definition and in my now working program delCard is a str ie: output from program <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

```py
c.execute ("DELETE from cards WHERE ROWID = ?", int(delCard));
```

Comment: @Popsimath when you run `execute`, it expects a string as a query for the first argument, then the second argument can be a single value, a tuple of values or a list that matches the number of `?` in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c.execute ("DELETE from cards WHERE ROWID = {}".format(int(delCard)));
```